# Using Python to append a list of names to a single URL during a crawl of a URL

Tags: python, url

I am looking to create a script that would crawl my URL and would append a name to the end of the url during a search. For example 192.168.1.100/map/**foo**

I would then want to parse through the response and if the status code is 200 and the content-length is 83. I would want to output it to a text file. If both these conditions are not matched then I will skip the printing of the URL.

Here is my rough idea. I am looking for some general direction.

I would start with the URL I would either read an array or a list, depending on the parameter length. I would then parse the response and look for the conditions. If true I would write the URL to a text document else I would continue the loop.

Thoughts? I'm not looking for you to write my code just to point me in the general direction.

Thanks

Here is the latest revision based on @German Petrov code.

```
import requests
import urlparse

url = "http://192.168.1.2/map/ShowPage.ashx?="
names = ["admin","backup","contact","index","logs","news","reboot",
              "register","test","users"]

with open("/root/Desktop/urls.txt", 'a') as urls:
    for name in names:
       newUrl = url + name
       r = requests.get(newUrl)
       c = r.content
       if r.status_code == 200 and (("Unknown" in c) <>1):
            urls.write(url + '\n')
```

WOW!!! SUPER STUPID ERROR on my part. It helps if I add http:// to the url.... 
Also no need to do the urlparse.urljoin as it cuts off my full url.

This is why I like my super easy C# ide :-D

Comment: I figured out that the content-length of the url's that don't exist is 73 so I can use the number 73 as false and any other number as true as long as the Header code is == 200.

Comment: So far I am looking at URLLib2, but I have never used that library. I figured I would read my list document and strip it of any excess characters then append it to the end of the URL. 

I was thinking I would read through the list, parse it into an array and then append the array at the end of each URL in the URL request. I would then grab the header and check the values for the Response Code and Content-Length.

Thoughts?

Comment: I strongly recommend looking at the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library if you're doing any kind of web crawling - it's much better than urllib for this kind of thing.

Comment: if you are going to use Python, why are declaring type of the variable? Python has dynamic cast and this is just one syntax error in your code. Please, read Pythonic syntax first: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out thanks to German who pointed me down the path.

```
import requests
import urlparse

url = "http://192.168.1.2/map/ShowPage.ashx?="
names = ["admin","backup","contact","index","logs","news","reboot",
              "register","test","users"]

with open("/root/Desktop/urls.txt", 'a') as urls:
    for name in names:
       newUrl = url + name
       r = requests.get(newUrl)
       c = r.content
       if r.status_code == 200 and (("Unknown" in c) <>1):
            urls.write(url + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

For the following, you have to install `requests`: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install

First

```
import requests
import urlparse

baseurl= "192.168.1.2/map/ShowPage.ashx?="
names = ["admin","backup","contact","index","logs","news","reboot",
              "register","test","users"]

for name in names:
    print urlparse.urljoin(baseurl, name)
```

gives you the following output:

```
192.168.1.2/map/admin
192.168.1.2/map/backup
192.168.1.2/map/contact
192.168.1.2/map/index
192.168.1.2/map/logs
192.168.1.2/map/news
192.168.1.2/map/reboot
192.168.1.2/map/register
192.168.1.2/map/test
192.168.1.2/map/users
```

Then you can update the code with get call:

```
import requests
import urlparse

baseurl = "192.168.1.2/map/ShowPage.ashx?="
names = ["admin","backup","contact","index","logs","news","reboot",
              "register","test","users"]

with open("C:\\urls.txt", 'a') as urls:    
    for name in names:
        url = urlparse.urljoin(baseurl, name)
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code == 200 and int(r.headers['content-length']) > 73: 
           urls.write(url) #Write it to the file
```

Comment: It's giving me a Syntax error on the = of, r = requests.get(newUrl)

Comment: whar error exactly? line indent? Note, that `requests` module should be pre-installed. I'll update the answer

Comment: Invalid syntax. I have the requests library installed according to python on my box. See my updated code at the beginning of the thread.

Comment: does it work for you, if you just execute my code? You have completely wrong python syntax in your example..